# Curl requests works but fails on python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm currently getting forbidden for a site I am trying to visit using requests library.

What's interesting is it seems to be working fine when using curl like this

```
curl 'https://www.zim.com/tools/track-a-shipment?consnumber=ZIMUHKG83103991' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
  -H 'Referer: https://www.zim.com/tools/track-a-shipment?consnumber=ZIMUHKG83103991' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Cookie: bm_sz=A9168FBFA535588B6FA41B389B0E0FC1~YAAQ5zLFF9vG5S52AQAA4DyEaQroeTnfUz1nzswWQ4xFrGAXCczEwMD0MIS+Fr9nA5Zs5CDuB/6MOUP/Q8maKyJJN1yTDoeodUjZt+5T/loHrw8YlbK3a0vO+29JspP04oee8T5lU9qct2gtHC60vbG94f3quPmuSVBERJbEnOG/Ju5QoQx9jsDMPQ==; AKA_A2=A; ak_bmsc=F05A9B88D5CE9314962A4FB53AC066FE17C532E756050000F179D95F94CDFE71~plTDPprwDhfZXi2vSQbthcJGHAoK6c1KvvX8PW2BvX9/io3C7PDJwH1q8MiYF2HN4xoooBKQWo3LvCfAKOWQaTOhy3Q+2auRG/2mn2fLiJxvIuju5c4huzOMGsxmM1BrVtWKf+fR4nnfdtodyimozv+SyFazbEbuHuq18ReiUyoP5KyXXlrsRkp3ReYMkve37Mm6n4x/8s7ZWSa7scVVthWDn02d9Dtp4buykLxcZCz1s=; rxVisitor=16080880493048D6AKB20IDEQSEGR1UGPHIO59J02C95B; uniqueUserId=73aa42f6-ec0a-454b-864c-53c929c69acc; stg_traffic_source_priority=1; country=US; _fbp=fb.1.1608088050866.874878324; _ga=GA1.2.1801289879.1608088051; _gid=GA1.2.1440505168.1608088051; _pk_ses.923228e7-d119-45eb-a025-e4d1b1af6e1b.ad39=*; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2020-12-16T03:07:34.685Z; dtCookie=v_4_srv_1_sn_5RCLUTEDABIFNF5FLA270N8NCOHUOMRF_perc_100000_ol_0_mul_1_app-3A25bc709b3f2362bb_0; TS0128f558=01bbeceaf7fc47a22dbac4f704c3f650720bf639f1b2b937dd7133075e6b113a96aa9c1b98d65581f9a2ca694795bd9b5c3403231723523f99d38545aaef94cf6cc57266cf; LPVID=MwZTliY2MwYjcwMDFmOTdi; LPSID-53134936=JThIkUaOQaGDwAiVk_mZWg; TS01f7aa8d=01bbeceaf7e716ede662d1632457f3471645d66c1808274488c7c06b899e5092889d3e65ade3ba07fd262b9063dd8f63ed770f2bef; stg_externalReferrer=https://www.zim.com/tools/track-a-shipment?consnumber=ZIMUHKG83103991; _abck=7AE32D3F4822078BCDBCB745422E19AE~0~YAAQ5zLFF4XV5S52AQAAOkGOaQUBzX68zlTJTRs1RP+1RohmAGbj05cNVwmJZIYznbQcOmT6NR0ccyXvbkmcczETVxvbyg4h9qiNQ9TNDh9aZrnqxQxttgA96/eKOY5iysj2qIM5Fg+RCBqlSS96tse+yduqQ+JV2OKFCgQC0CR+5Fvr8nngGjIGVqsV/wC4vNGBQX6oqf1YHMxx8rN36mEzTfOpQvUAVU1iN0fuK98Rpu16LFgJU05GRxd/trtTYKDx8AX6SSdjpGyNIvJWOKg30wO7ALYMjALr3pPiWh23sF6McV3nOJVONoGZpBrK6bhEOfQAeUnqkYT4aySK1JebTA==~-1~-1~-1; dtLatC=37; OptanonConsent=isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Tue+Dec+15+2020+19%3A18%3A19+GMT-0800+(Pacific+Standard+Time)&version=5.14.0&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=1%3A1%2C2%3A1&AwaitingReconsent=false; _pk_id.923228e7-d119-45eb-a025-e4d1b1af6e1b.ad39=e4e8f967bd0568d5.1608088052.1.1608088700.1608088052.; bm_sv=DA4D33FF58BFFFC86A150B9B747988EC~oo1jX8ygs4LrnU4muVv/GaJaPJk2Jiolx5z0YcxGR4jlocdv9gImCEfeD3qrIbuauRTjMQYhGgV9HfY6u+d2QkpVguGGBIc92tToxRY4Ht3kXG+UqE5NpoBKiBhweyNtt/LIFRgTDDA1v4zQc8EkBw==; rxvt=1608090500507|1608088049306; dtPC=1$88698827_281h-vKTCJGFJVHKAFAPRGCSPMAVPCDVLMHPUJ-0e8; dtSa=true%7CC%7C-1%7CTrack%20Shipment%7C-%7C1608089388256%7C88698827_281%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.zim.com%2Ftools%2Ftrack-a-shipment%3Fconsnumber%3DZIMUHKG83103991%7CTrack%20Shipment%5Ec%20Container%20Tracing%20%5Ep%20ZIM%7C1608088700148%7C%7C; RT="sl=4&ss=1608088049148&tt=11039&obo=0&sh=1608088700486%3D4%3A0%3A11039%2C1608088668289%3D3%3A0%3A9023%2C1608088063737%3D2%3A0%3A5494%2C1608088051968%3D1%3A0%3A2818&dm=zim.com&si=puidioyg8d8&rl=1&ld=1608088700486&nu=&cl=1608089388285&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zim.com%2Ftools%2Ftrack-a-shipment%3F201a15c26295707f7d9507ad6c103a3f&ul=1608089388315"; stg_last_interaction=Wed%2C%2016%20Dec%202020%2003:29:48%20GMT; stg_returning_visitor=Wed%2C%2016%20Dec%202020%2003:29:48%20GMT' \
  --compressed
```

Doing the same exact thing in request and making sure I am passing every header correctly, the site still seem to give me forbidden error. I understand this is done for security on their side, but it seems to be working fine using curl, what could be different?

My python requests look like this:

```
headers = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
        'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
        'Referer': 'https://www.zim.com/tools/track-a-shipment',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',        
 'Cookie':'bm_sz=A9168FBFA535588B6FA41B389B0E0FC1~YAAQ5zLFF9vG5S52AQAA4DyEaQroeTnfUz1nzswWQ4xFrGAXCczEwMD0MIS+Fr9nA5Zs5CDuB/6MOUP/Q8maKyJJN1yTDoeodUjZt+5T/loHrw8YlbK3a0vO+29JspP04oee8T5lU9qct2gtHC60vbG94f3quPmuSVBERJbEnOG/Ju5QoQx9jsDMPQ==; AKA_A2=A; ak_bmsc=F05A9B88D5CE9314962A4FB53AC066FE17C532E756050000F179D95F94CDFE71~plTDPprwDhfZXi2vSQbthcJGHAoK6c1KvvX8PW2BvX9/io3C7PDJwH1q8MiYF2HN4xoooBKQWo3LvCfAKOWQaTOhy3Q+2auRG/2mn2fLiJxvIuju5c4huzOMGsxmM1BrVtWKf+fR4nnfdtodyimozv+SyFazbEbuHuq18ReiUyoP5KyXXlrsRkp3ReYMkve37Mm6n4x/8s7ZWSa7scVVthWDn02d9Dtp4buykLxcZCz1s=; rxVisitor=16080880493048D6AKB20IDEQSEGR1UGPHIO59J02C95B; uniqueUserId=73aa42f6-ec0a-454b-864c-53c929c69acc; stg_traffic_source_priority=1; country=US; _fbp=fb.1.1608088050866.874878324; _ga=GA1.2.1801289879.1608088051; _gid=GA1.2.1440505168.1608088051; _pk_ses.923228e7-d119-45eb-a025-e4d1b1af6e1b.ad39=*; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2020-12-16T03:07:34.685Z; dtCookie=v_4_srv_1_sn_5RCLUTEDABIFNF5FLA270N8NCOHUOMRF_perc_100000_ol_0_mul_1_app-3A25bc709b3f2362bb_0; TS0128f558=01bbeceaf7fc47a22dbac4f704c3f650720bf639f1b2b937dd7133075e6b113a96aa9c1b98d65581f9a2ca694795bd9b5c3403231723523f99d38545aaef94cf6cc57266cf; LPVID=MwZTliY2MwYjcwMDFmOTdi; LPSID-53134936=JThIkUaOQaGDwAiVk_mZWg; TS01f7aa8d=01bbeceaf7e716ede662d1632457f3471645d66c1808274488c7c06b899e5092889d3e65ade3ba07fd262b9063dd8f63ed770f2bef; stg_externalReferrer=https://www.zim.com/tools/track-a-shipment?consnumber=ZIMUHKG83103991; _abck=7AE32D3F4822078BCDBCB745422E19AE~0~YAAQ5zLFF4XV5S52AQAAOkGOaQUBzX68zlTJTRs1RP+1RohmAGbj05cNVwmJZIYznbQcOmT6NR0ccyXvbkmcczETVxvbyg4h9qiNQ9TNDh9aZrnqxQxttgA96/eKOY5iysj2qIM5Fg+RCBqlSS96tse+yduqQ+JV2OKFCgQC0CR+5Fvr8nngGjIGVqsV/wC4vNGBQX6oqf1YHMxx8rN36mEzTfOpQvUAVU1iN0fuK98Rpu16LFgJU05GRxd/trtTYKDx8AX6SSdjpGyNIvJWOKg30wO7ALYMjALr3pPiWh23sF6McV3nOJVONoGZpBrK6bhEOfQAeUnqkYT4aySK1JebTA==~-1~-1~-1; dtLatC=37; OptanonConsent=isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Tue+Dec+15+2020+19%3A18%3A19+GMT-0800+(Pacific+Standard+Time)&version=5.14.0&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=1%3A1%2C2%3A1&AwaitingReconsent=false; _pk_id.923228e7-d119-45eb-a025-e4d1b1af6e1b.ad39=e4e8f967bd0568d5.1608088052.1.1608088700.1608088052.; bm_sv=DA4D33FF58BFFFC86A150B9B747988EC~oo1jX8ygs4LrnU4muVv/GaJaPJk2Jiolx5z0YcxGR4jlocdv9gImCEfeD3qrIbuauRTjMQYhGgV9HfY6u+d2QkpVguGGBIc92tToxRY4Ht3kXG+UqE5NpoBKiBhweyNtt/LIFRgTDDA1v4zQc8EkBw==; rxvt=1608090500507|1608088049306; dtPC=1$88698827_281h-vKTCJGFJVHKAFAPRGCSPMAVPCDVLMHPUJ-0e8; dtSa=true%7CC%7C-1%7CTrack%20Shipment%7C-%7C1608089388256%7C88698827_281%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.zim.com%2Ftools%2Ftrack-a-shipment%3Fconsnumber%3DZIMUHKG83103991%7CTrack%20Shipment%5Ec%20Container%20Tracing%20%5Ep%20ZIM%7C1608088700148%7C%7C; RT="sl=4&ss=1608088049148&tt=11039&obo=0&sh=1608088700486%3D4%3A0%3A11039%2C1608088668289%3D3%3A0%3A9023%2C1608088063737%3D2%3A0%3A5494%2C1608088051968%3D1%3A0%3A2818&dm=zim.com&si=puidioyg8d8&rl=1&ld=1608088700486&nu=&cl=1608089388285&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zim.com%2Ftools%2Ftrack-a-shipment%3F201a15c26295707f7d9507ad6c103a3f&ul=1608089388315"; stg_last_interaction=Wed%2C%2016%20Dec%202020%2003:29:48%20GMT; stg_returning_visitor=Wed%2C%2016%20Dec%202020%2003:29:48%20GMT'
    }

    params = (
        ('consnumber', 'ZIMUHKG83103991'),
    )

    response = requests.get('https://www.zim.com/tools/track-a-shipment', headers=headers, params=params)
```

I even make sure to pass the same exact cookie, it still fails.

Comment: I'm pretty sure requests urlencodes headers by default, while curl doesn't

Comment: Maybe you can tcpdump the data packet to make sure what you have maked sure.

Comment: @SuperStormer does that mean I would have to urldecode it?

Answer (score 0):

you can change
params = (
('consnumber', 'ZIMUHKG83103991'),
)

to  dict type params = {
'consnumber':'ZIMUHKG83103991'
} try again

Comment: That didn't do anything, still gave access denied.

Comment: Check if the curl command still works. It does not work for me now. It just waits forever. And params should be dict type instead of tuple as mino mentioned.